# Pandas dataframe create new column after x rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to create a new DataFrame based on some data in a CSV file.

My Data is of the form:

```
1, 81.99525117808678
2, 78.79210736916842
3, 69.33703048261454
4, 53.12612416937101
5, 48.8442549498639
6, 48.8442549498639
7, 38.96011640562207
8, 33.66251691693962
9, 29.202159649144907
10, 27.77726568480279
1, 81.99525117808678
2, 78.79210736916842
3, 69.33703048261454
4, 53.12612416937101
5, 48.8442549498639
6, 48.8442549498639
7, 38.96011640562207
8, 33.66251691693962
9, 29.202159649144907
10, 27.77726568480279
```

With the first number representing the index, and the second representing the value. I'd like to create a new column for each unique run. For example:

```
Index:       Run 1:             Run 2:
1,           81.99525117808678, 81.99525117808678
2,           78.79210736916842, 78.79210736916842
3,           69.33703048261454, 69.33703048261454
4,           53.12612416937101, 53.12612416937101
5,           48.8442549498639, 48.8442549498639
6,           48.8442549498639, 48.8442549498639
7,           38.96011640562207, 38.96011640562207
8,           33.66251691693962, 33.66251691693962
9,           29.202159649144907, 29.202159649144907
10,          27.77726568480279, 27.77726568480279
```

So far I have the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, names=['Generation', 'Fitness'], index_col=0)
```

This produces the result:

```
0   
1   81.995251
2   78.792107
3   69.337030
4   53.126124
5   48.844255
6   48.844255
7   38.960116
8   33.662517
9   29.202160
10  27.777266
1   81.995251
2   78.792107
3   69.337030
4   53.126124
5   48.844255
6   48.844255
7   38.960116
8   33.662517
9   29.202160
10  27.777266
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `reader` iterable (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) for details), with a chunk size of 10, then concatenate each chunk:

```
reader = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', chunksize=10,
                       index_col=0, header=None, names=['Generation', 'Fitness'])

my_df = pd.concat((chunk for chunk in reader), axis=1)

>>> my_df
              Fitness    Fitness
Generation                      
1           81.995251  81.995251
2           78.792107  78.792107
3           69.337030  69.337030
4           53.126124  53.126124
5           48.844255  48.844255
6           48.844255  48.844255
7           38.960116  38.960116
8           33.662517  33.662517
9           29.202160  29.202160
10          27.777266  27.777266
```

If you need the column names as you had them, you can rename them with a list comprehension:

```
# python 3.6 or above
my_df.columns = [f'Run {i}' for i, _ in enumerate(my_df.columns,1)]
# Or:
my_df.columns = ['Run {}'.format(i) for i, _ in enumerate(my_df.columns,1)]
# Or:
my_df.columns = range(1,len(list(df))+1)
my_df = my_df.add_prefix('Run ')


>>> my_df
                Run 1      Run 2
Generation                      
1           81.995251  81.995251
2           78.792107  78.792107
3           69.337030  69.337030
4           53.126124  53.126124
5           48.844255  48.844255
6           48.844255  48.844255
7           38.960116  38.960116
8           33.662517  33.662517
9           29.202160  29.202160
10          27.777266  27.777266
```